# AppIntro Android Library. How can i use fragments with its xml and .java?

Tags: android

AppIntro is an Android Library that helps you make a cool intro for your app.

[AppIntro Library](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro)

```
    // Add your slide's fragments here
    // AppIntro will automatically generate the dots indicator and buttons.
    addSlide(first_fragment);
    addSlide(second_fragment);
    addSlide(third_fragment);
    addSlide(fourth_fragment);
```

But when I try to attach a fragment created by me, I get an error.

[image]

And this is the error:

[image]

**How can i do to add my fragment1?**

Comment: SampleSlide is of a different type. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

While `addSlide()` method needs `android.supportv4.app.Fragment` as parameter, so your custom `Fragment1` should extend from `android.supportv4.app.Fragment` class.

Answer (score 0):

1、

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

2、

```
public class Slide_First extends  Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_first, null);
        return view;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

first: create your fragments like always and add the xml elements you need to it, and in your activity just do this

Edit: It is not necessary to extend to AppIntro or AppIntro2

```
public class MyIntro extends AppIntro2 implements ISlidePolicy {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        Intro1 fragment1 = new Intro1 ();
        Intro2 fragment2 = new Intro2 ();
        Intro3 fragment3 = new Intro3 ();
        addSlide (fragment1);
        addSlide (fragment2);
        addSlide (fragment3);

//Only personalization
        showStatusBar (false);
        showSkipButton (false);
        setFadeAnimation ();
        setBarColor (Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
}
```

Edit2: import these dependences in your fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```